# Bash/sh 'if else' statement

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I want to understand the `if else` statement in `sh` scripting.

So I wrote the below to find out **whether JAVA_HOME is set in the environment or not**. I wrote the below script

```
#!/bin/sh
if [ $JAVA_HOME != "" ]
then
    echo $JAVA_HOME
else
    echo "NO JAVA HOME SET"
fi
```

This my output to `env`:

```
sh-3.2$ env

SHELL=/bin/csh
TERM=xterm
HOST=estilor
SSH_CLIENT=10.15.16.28 4348 22
SSH_TTY=/dev/pts/18
USER=asimonraj
GROUP=ccusers
HOSTTYPE=x86_64-linux
PATH=/usr/local/bin:/bin:/home/asimonraj/java/LINUXJAVA/java/bin:/usr/bin
MAIL=/var/mail/asimonraj
PWD=/home/asimonraj/nix
HOME=/home/asimonraj
SHLVL=10
OSTYPE=linux
VENDOR=unknown
LOGNAME=asimonraj
MACHTYPE=x86_64
SSH_CONNECTION=100.65.116.248 4348 100.65.116.127 22
_=/bin/env
```

But I get the below output:

```
sh-3.2$ ./test.sh
./test.sh: line 3: [: !=: unary operator expected
NO JAVA HOME SET
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You're running into a stupid limitation of the way `sh` expands arguments. Line 3 of your script is being expanded to:

```
if [ != ]
```

Which `sh` can't figure out what to do with. Try this nasty hack on for size:

```
if [ x$JAVA_HOME != x ]
```

Both arguments have to be non-empty, so we'll just throw an `x` into both of them and see what happens.

Alternatively, there's a separate operator for testing if a string is non-empty:

```
if [ !-z $JAVA_HOME ]
```

(`-z` tests if the following string is empty.)

Comment: @Keith Thompson: @diskwuff describes the standard convention here. It also works if `$JAVA_HOME` is set to other things `test` will choke on, although I notice that `bash` is pretty lenient.

Comment: @reinierpost: Are you saying that the "x" prefix is the standard convention? It probably was at one time, but I don't think it's necessary today, and I rarely see it. The operands don't have to be non-empty, they just have to be single "words" (where a word can be the empty string). (It may be that some very old shells didn't distinguish between an argument of `""` and no argument at all, but I'd be surprised if any shell in common current use had that problem.)

Comment: OK, it's probably outdated. I'm sure there are still lots of Unix machines with `/bin/sh`es other than bash, but you're right, it generally doesn't appear to be much of an issue these days.

Comment: -1: `[ x$JAVA_HOME != x ]` is **completely** the wrong way to solve this problem; it causes other bugs. (Look at what happens if your `JAVA_HOME` contains a space, or, worse, a wildcard that matches content in the current directory... or, if the `nullglob` option is set, a wildcard character that _doesn't_ match).

Comment: @reinierpost, that "standard convention" was created to work around bugs in 1970s-era shells. Those shells have been gone for decades. It's an antiquated convention, and should no longer be taught.

Comment: `sh` knows exactly what to do with `[ != ]`.  It invokes the `[` command with the arguments `!=` and `]`, and the `[` utility (whether builtin to the shell or the external command) knows exactly what to do with the arguments `!=` and `]`: it treats them as an error and reports the error.  This is not a limitation of the way the shell expands arguments; it is simply the way it is done.

Answer (score 3):

```
if [ -z $JAVA_HOME  ]  
then  
    echo $JAVA_HOME  
else  
    echo "NO JAVA HOME SET"  
fi
```

Comment: [Use four-spaces to indent blocks of code](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code), it makes them easier to read.  (Or just highlight the code, and click the `{}` button.)

Comment: @OverZealous: I tried that but it is not working even pressing 4 times spacebar , i don't find any change in output preview.

Comment: Well, I'd fix it for you, but I'm required to make 6 non-whitespace character changes, and your example is fine.  You have to have 4 extra spaces in front of each line, and remove the backticks.  (Or just use the toolbar.)

Comment: @kracekumar: I get `./test.sh: line 2: [: -ne: unary operator expected
NO JAVA HOME SET
`

Comment: @Abhishek Simon : In case you want to check it is empty, use -z switch.

Comment: -1: Needs more quotes. Should be `[ -z "$JAVA_HOME" ]` to be correct.

Answer (score 3):

The `-n` and `-z` options are tests that should be used here:

```
if [ -n "$JAVAHOME" ]; then
    echo "$JAVAHOME";
else
    echo "\$JAVAHOME not set";
fi
```

Comment: I'd suggest using single-quotes rather than double-quotes and escaping in the case where you don't want expansion to occur. Otherwise, looks good.

Answer (score 1):

Note that if you want to determine if a variable is set, you probably do not want to use either if/else or test ([).  It is more typical to do things like:

```
# Abort if JAVA_HOME is not set (or empty)
: ${JAVA_HOME:?JAVA_HOME is unset}
```

or

```
# report the value of JAVA_HOME, or a default value
echo ${JAVA_HOME:-default value}
```

or

```
# Assign JAVA_HOME if it is unset (or empty)
: ${JAVAHOME:=default value}
```

Comment: The echo case needs more quotes. Otherwise, this is the best answer I've seen here so far (the lack of quality is somewhat discouraging).

Comment: If JAVA_HOME contains path elements with spaces, there are more problems with the system than can be solved with double quotes!

Comment: Just because it would be bad practice to choose a filename or location that would trigger bugs in buggy programs is no excuse for those programs to be buggy.

Comment: Create a directory named `var:bin` in `/usr`.  Install program `foo` in `/usr/var:bin`.  Put `/usr/var:bin` in PATH.  What is the bug that prevents the shell from being able to find `foo` in the PATH?